# Trying to use PFQueryTableViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

All,

I have a ViewController with a TableView in it. In the Tableview I have a prototype cell designed and it has a subclass and its subclassed with PFTableViewCell.

As I have a view controller and a tableview in it, I have created this class on my view controller.

```
class ViewController:  PFQueryTableViewController         {
```

but as its not a tableviewcontroller will PFQueryTableViewController work ? As I am getting horrible errors like :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "vXZ-lx-hvc-view-kh9-bI-dsS" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
```

Any ideas guys ? I need it as a ViewController because there are other things on the screen besides just a TableView.

Comment: I think you're on the right track.  Just make the ViewController a subclass of UIViewController.  (PFQueryTableViewController writes some of the parse/tableview logic for you, but its better to learn and build this yourself).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `container` to your `UIViewcontroller` in your storyboard. It will create a `UIViewController` automatically. But you can delete it and add your `PFQueryTableViewController` instead.

After that you can right click(and hold) from the container to your `PFQueryTableViewController` and connect the both components and choose `embed`.